# Elasticsearch Multi-field Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have configured an Elasticsearch index with two fields : "Name" and "Type".
When I execute the query below, I don't get any result because "actor" is in the "Type" field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "johnny depp actor",
      "operator": "AND",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "type"
      ],
      "tieBreaker": 0.7
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to execute a query with a number of words, and to get results even if some words are in the "Name" field and others in the "Type" field.

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. 
For those who probably need it, the solution is to use [cross-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields), so that **all terms** must be present in **at least one field** for a document to match.

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "johnny depp actor",
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "operator": "AND",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "type"
      ],
      "tieBreaker": 0.7
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
      "should":[
        {"match_phrase":{"name":"johnny depp actor"}},
        {"match_phrase":{"type":"johnny depp actor"}},
        {"match_phrase":{"name":"johnny"}},
        {"match_phrase":{"name":"depp"}},
        {"match_phrase":{"name":"actor"}},
        {"match_phrase":{"type":"johnny depp actor"}},
        {"match_phrase":{"type":"johnny"}},
        {"match_phrase":{"type":"depp"}},
        {"match_phrase":{"type":"actor"}},
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it actually works, but if the user types "jean claude van damme actor " you will have to add all the combinations.